# Gradle DSL method not found: 'packageNameSuffix()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a problem with the Gradle in Android Studio

Error :

> Error:(37, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'packageNameSuffix()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'FilHarmonie' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Gradle settings
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 13):

This was changed to `applicationIdSuffix` several months ago, with the old name removed in November. [Here is some documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) regarding the differences between `packageName` and `applicationId`.

Comment: I have this message : "Cannot resolve symbol applicationIdSuffix"

Comment: @MichelRobico: Then perhaps you have it in the wrong place. `applicationIdSuffix` can be used in a build type. See the documentation that I linked to above for an example. If you have further problems, please edit your question and post your `build.gradle` file where you are trying to use `applicationIdSuffix`.